# Print only the numbers in the string in python

Tags: python, string, integer

I need to print only the numbers in the string and I don't know how to do it
I mean for example mystring="ab543", How to get 543 as int?

I tried something like that

```
my_string="ab543"
numlst=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
countfinish=0
whichnum=""
for charr in my_string:
    for num in numlst:
        if num==charr:
            whichnum=whichnum+str(num)
    break
    countfinish=countfinish+int(whichnum)
print(countfinish)
```

Comment: Are the digits in the input string guaranteed to be contiguous or can they be interspersed with letters as well (e.g. "ab62t6yd63" => 62663)?

Comment: Why you're `break`ing?

Comment: Are there only integers?

Comment: not only integers

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> my_string="ab543"
>>> "".join([str(s) for s in my_string if s.isdigit()])
'543'
>>> int("".join([str(s) for s in my_string if s.isdigit()]))
543
```

You also can use `filter` :

```
>>> my_string="ab543"
>>> int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, my_string)))
543
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
pattern = "\d+[.]?\d*"
re.findall(pattern, my_string)
```

The pattern used here should give you also float numbers.
For example if `my_string="ab543ab2392alsow435.32"`, then you get the following output:

`['543', '2392', '435.32']`

Afterwards you can use the `int()` function to convert them to ints.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's the answer you were looking for, but you could try to use .isdigit() to check if a character is a number.

```
my_string="ab543"
numbers = []
for i in my_string:
    if (i.isdigit()):
        numbers.append(i)
final = "".join(numbers)
print(final) # prints 543
print(int(final)) # prints 543
```

Comment: `line="rk2 c55 Q3 wWw67 10"  
print(line.split())
numm=""
count=0
for elem in line:
    for char in elem:
        if char.isdigit()==True:
            numm=numm+char
    count=count+int(numm)
print (count)`
I got error

Comment: Why do you have 2 for loops in here?